# Prettyphoto lightbox height, width setting for inline html content?

Tags: jquery, html

I am showing both inline html with image and other contents on popup box, side by side like facebook image viewer but, I am getting wired size of popub box and it doesn't re-size itself according to the contents.

I tried with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
default_width: 800,
default_height: 520,
});
});
```

But this doesn't help, Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: is the 800 then translated as pixels? Can you style the generated Box?

Comment: yes it get translated but I want it dynamically resize.